# How can I make this variadic template code shorter using features from C++14 and C++1z?

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, c++17

This is a code snippet that I am going to use in order to check whether the variadic template types are unique:

```
template <typename...>
struct is_one_of;

template <typename F>
struct is_one_of<F> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename F, typename S, typename... T>
struct is_one_of<F, S, T...> {
    static constexpr bool value =
        std::is_same<F, S>::value || is_one_of<F, T...>::value;
};

template <typename...>
struct is_unique;

template <>
struct is_unique<> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename F, typename... T>
struct is_unique<F, T...> {
    static constexpr bool value =
        is_unique<T...>::value && !is_one_of<F, T...>::value;
};

int main() {
    constexpr bool b = is_unique<bool, int, double>::value;
    constexpr bool c = is_unique<int, char, int>::value;
    static_assert(b == true && c == false, "!");
}
```

Is there any way to make this code shorter and/or more concise using features introduced in C++14 and C++1z? Or is there a better way to achieve the same effect using the new features?

In the case of C++1z I mean: features that are already available in the newest versions of Clang and GCC.

Comment: No, that's pretty concise as is.  When fold expressions are introduced, though, you'll be able to do something like:

`constexpr static bool value = std::is_same<F, T>::value || ...`

Comment: @BrianRodriguez: That needs round parentheses I think.

Comment: You can use a little trickery to make  the `is_one_of` a little more concise: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b9755f28193a13b

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki yes, exactly. Does it use any new features (that were not present in C++11 or not developed to that stage) other than fold expressions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool is_one_of = (std::is_same<F, Ts>{} || ...);

template <typename...>
constexpr bool is_unique = true;

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool is_unique<F, Ts...> = is_unique<Ts...> && !is_one_of<F, Ts...>;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d392535188b2e1f)

Answer (score 10):

We recently added [std::disjunction](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0013r1.html) to the C++1z draft, which can be used for `is_one_of` (and it stops instantiating as soon as it finds a match, see the link for more details):

```
template <typename F, typename... T>
  using is_one_of = std::disjunction<is_same<F, T>...>;
```

This is already implemented in GCC trunk. For older versions of GCC you can use the implementation detail `__or_` instead:

```
template <typename F, typename... T>
  using is_one_of = std::__or_<is_same<F, T>...>;
```

Or implement `disjunction` by hand using C++11 facilities, as shown at the end of the proposal linked to above.

Answer (score 3):

I'd (now) suggest using the `std::conj/disj/nega` family of STL functions:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename H, typename... T>
struct is_one_of : std::disjunction<std::is_same<H, T>...> {};

template <typename H, typename... T>
struct is_unique : std::conjunction<std::negation<std::is_same<H, T>>..., is_unique<T...>> {};

template <typename H>
struct is_unique<H> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_one_of<int, char, double, int, bool>::value);
    static_assert(is_unique<int, char, double, bool>::value);
    static_assert(!is_unique<int, int, char, double, bool>::value);
}
```

---

When [fold-expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4191.html), which were designed for these cases, are released into the language this will become trivial:

```
namespace stx = std::experimental;

template <typename H, typename... T>
struct is_one_of {
    static constexpr bool value = (stx::is_same_v<H, T> || ...);
};

template <typename H, typename... T>
struct is_unique {
    static constexpr bool value = (!stx::is_same_v<H, T> && ... && is_unique<T...>::value);
};

template <typename H>
struct is_unique<H> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: Your `is_unique` only checks if `H` is unique, but other `T`s could still have duplicates in the type list.

Comment: This code is broken in so many different ways that it's clear that it has never been even minimally tested.

Comment: @T.C. I'll change it when I wake up tomorrow. I only just recently gave myself access to these new features, and forgot to fix this while having so much fun and etc

Comment: @T.C. Done.  All that's keeping it from compiling now is the `constexpr`-ness of `std::any_of`

Answer (score 2):

I'm in line with Brian Rodriguez's and Piotr Scontnincki's answers, as far as it concerns the fold expressions part. Until folding expressions are in, you could shrink the existing code a little bit by getting rid of the incomplete primary templates as follows:

```
template <typename...>
struct is_one_of {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename F, typename S, typename... T>
struct is_one_of<F, S, T...> {
    static constexpr bool value =
        std::is_same<F, S>::value || is_one_of<F, T...>::value;
};

template <typename...>
struct is_unique {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename F, typename... T>
struct is_unique<F, T...> {
    static constexpr bool value = is_unique<T...>::value && !is_one_of<F, T...>::value;
};
```