# How can I enable nested class template only for parent class variadic template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In my program I have following code:

```
template<typename... Args>
class Outer {
    template<typename Arg>
    class Inner {
        //some code
    }
}
```

How can I restrict `Arg` to be one of the types in Args template pack?

Comment: The code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025327/how-can-i-make-this-variadic-template-code-shorter-using-features-from-c14-and) tells you how to write an `is_one_of` trait. From there it's a simple `static_assert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct contains : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename F, typename... Ts>
struct contains<T, F, Ts...> : contains<T, Ts...> {};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct contains<T, T, Ts...> : std::true_type {};

template <typename... Args>
struct Outer
{
    template <typename Arg>
    struct Inner
    {
        static_assert(contains<Arg, Args...>::value, "Arg must be from Args");
    };
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d6bfa340cd3f3ad)