# Is there a short way to check if parameter pack doesn't contain types repetition?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, c++17

Let's say I have a template structure:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct Foo {
    static_assert(/*code*/);
    //to do
}
```

I want to check in static_assert if types in `Args` are all different types. I know how to do it using additional template structures and template specialization. Maybe there exists a one-line solution for this problem? I can use C++17

The linked question was asked 2 years ago and maybe there is a shorter solution which uses for example multiple pack expansion somehow.

Comment: when you do std::get<T> in you for_each loop ( that you have to create ) you should get compile time error if there is a duplicate. Would that do?

Comment: std::get<T> should be applied in a tuple made from the arguments .

Comment: @g24l: something like that [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf7f114488c75f16).

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d29f503a45aa9892)'s a possible solution using `std::experimental::disjunction` and friends.

Comment: @Jarod42 , yes exactly what I meant. It's a same this was marked duplicate, I don't see how it is answered in the linked post. whatever, moving on.

Comment: @101010 those are all C++11 solutions in that question.  Admittedly when you closed it the OP did not mention C++17, but there was C++14.  ;)  Reopening, as C++14/C++17 does admit much improved solutions.

Comment: C++14 > SOLUTIONS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025327/how-can-i-make-this-variadic-template-code-shorter-using-features-from-c14-and

Comment: @101010 Awesome, reclosed with that one!